# Installing through kick start file - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have created a kick start file. Can any one explain the procedure to install Ubuntu through kick start file.I mean if I want to install a Ubuntu on a system through kick start file, where should I keep the kick start file.

And say that all my setup files are in a USB or a CD.

And how do I invoke kick start.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create a kickstart file?

"Kickstart" is the name for the process on Red Hat and Fedora Linux.

As far as I know, on Debian and Ubuntu systems, you need to use something else, like [FAI](http://wiki.debian.org/FAI).

[More details on FAI](http://fai-project.org/)